# Issue with current time in pandas to_datetime

Tags: pandas, timestamp, python-datetime

I am trying to get current timestamp using the following code:

```
pd.to_datetime('now')
```

But this is returning me the timestamp value with a delay of 1 hour.
Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: It's in utc do you happen to be in a tz an hour off of utc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local time zone is different from the time zone used by Pandas. By default, Pandas uses UTC time as its reference time zone. To convert the current time to your local time zone, you can use the `tz_localize` method and specify your local time zone.Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd

timestamp = pd.to_datetime('now')
local_timestamp = timestamp.tz_localize(tz='UTC').tz_convert('US/Pacific')
print(local_timestamp)
```

which gives

```
2023-02-12 22:26:16.938851-08:00
```